# Angular Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm having problem with following error while creating "recaptchaVerifier" for phone number authentication with AungularFire.

I have initialized Firebase in my app.module.ts as follow:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
```

And I made sure to import AngularFireAuthModule afterwards. Then from my registration component, I am creating RecaptchaVerifier like

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      'recaptcha-container',
      {
        size: 'invisible',
      }
    )
  }
```

And I am receiving this error message:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__["default"].auth.RecaptchaVerifier')

This error goes away if I initialize the App again in `app.module.ts` like this before `@NgModule` declaration.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
```

I looked all over Internet and found no one has done like this. I'm wondering what I have done wrong. Your help is much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: At first glance it looks like the registration component is loaded in a new page, which means it needs to initialize its own Firebase app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. The registration component is also declared in `app.module.ts`.